# Selectively replace words with regular expressions

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, pcre

Is it possible with regular expressions to selectively replace certain words?

My document contains several lines like this:

```
<type>xxx</type>
```

Where `xxx`can be `bug`, `improvement`, `newfeature`, and several other values.

I want to convert this to:

```
"kind":"yyy",
```

Where `yyy` = `xxx`, *except* that `improvement` should be replaced with `enhancement`, and `newfeature` with `proposal`. In all other cases, `yyy` should be the same as `xxx`.

The straight-forward regex would replace `<type>([^<]+)</type>` with `"kind":"$1",`, but is it possible to replace those two special words at the same time?

I believe I am using the PCRE engine.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do with 1 replacement operation. You will most probably get answers with work-arounds.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: The regex language is PCRE. I'm not using a programming language, just an advanced text editor to do replacements in a long code file.

Comment: So what is the text editor?

Comment: The text editor is Sublime Text, stable channel, build 3065.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to put conditional statements in a replacement string or to store datas (that are not in the string) in the pattern itself.

The more simple way with sublimetext is obviously to proceed in several steps *(replace special strings before, and replace the general case after)*. The good way is to use a programming language and an xml parser.

But it is possible to make a replaceAll in one shot with a trick:

1) add this line at the very end of your file (in a new line):

```
#improvement:enhancement#newfeature:proposal#"kind":"
```

2) use this pattern:

```
<type>(?|([^<]+)</type>(?=(?:.*\R)++#(?>[^:]+:[^#]+#)??\1:([^#]++).*#((.).*))|(([^<]+))</type>(?=(?:.*\R)++.*#((.).*)))|\R.*\z
```

with this replacement:

```
$3$2$4
```

*(`$3` stands for `"kind":"` or nothing, `$2` stands for `enhancement`, `proposal`, `xxx` or nothing, `$4` stands for `"` or nothing.)*

3) replaceAll

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC7bF7/1)

The idea was simple: putting all the replacement content in the string itself, and using a branch reset `(?|.(..).|.(..).)` in the pattern *(with this feature capture groups in each alternative have the same numbers)*. The added line is automatically removed.

Note: if you have more than two special terms to replace, complete the last line *(but `"kind":"` must stay at the end)*, and change `??` in the pattern with `*?`.

pattern details:

```
<type>
(?|                        # open a branch reset group
                           # first branch: the special terms
    ([^<]+)                # capture the term in group 1
    </type>
    (?=                    # open a lookahead (nothing is consumed inside it)
        (?:.*\R)++ #       # reach the last line
        (?>[^:]+:[^#]+#)?? # skip a couple of term:repl if needed
        \1                 # until the content of group 1 is found
        : ([^#]++)         # capture the corresponding replacement
        .* #               # reach the last #
        ((.).*)            # capture '"kind":"' in group 3 and '"' in group 4
    )                      # close the lookahead
  |                        # OR second branch: the general case
    (([^<]+))              # capture the term in group 1 and 2
                           # (to have the same number than the previous branch)
    </type>
    (?=                    # open a lookahead
        (?:.*\R)++         # same thing than the previous branch
        .* #               # but this time only '"kind":"' and '"'
        ((.).*)            # are needed
    )
)                          # close the branch reset group
|                          # OR
\R.*\z                     # the last line (in this case all the
                           # groups are empty)
```

`\R` is an alias for several types of newlines (whatever the system).

`(?>....)` is an atomic group.

`++`, `*+`, `?+` are possessive quantifiers.

`\z` is an anchor for the end of the string.

Comment: Wow, that is a really great solution. There are several operators there that I need to learn more about, but this is definitely getting me started! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a quick question: the `++`, `(?>)` and `??` are performance optimizations and reach the same results as `+`, `(?:)` and `*?` respectively, correct?

Comment: @Peter: There are no general rules. For example `(?:.*\R)++` ensures that what follows is in the last line, when `(?:.*\R)+` doesn't since backtracking is possible. `??` (or `*?`) is a choice, I prefer to advance couple by couple until I reach the good one instead of matching all couples and backtracking one by one to find it. `(?>...)` improves indeed performances but the main goal is to "move" couple by couple without to take care of what contains the group (with `(?:...)` the regex engine records each bactracking position for all characters in the group, but not with `(?>..)`)

Comment: @Peter: `??` is only the non-greedy version of `?` and `*?` the non-greedy version of `*`. Take a look at www.rexegg.com that contains great explanations about notions like greedy/non-greedy, possessive quantifiers/atomic groups..